# How to change green background to transparent in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

[image: Can you see the Green background. I want to remove that.]

So I want to change the green color that is coming either side of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing  color preferences for **Injected language fragment** (**Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General, Code**) - clear the **Background**